# Linking a user id to a profile model - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, devise, scaffolding

I have a basic rails app with devise set up and a profile model generated with scaffolding. The Profile model is where the user will add detailed information about themselves after they sign up. Everything is working fine except for one issue: after the user creates a profile, the new profile is created however it is not linked to that user id. I have generated the migration to add user_id to profile. How can I make the profile that the user creates get saved and linked to the currently signed in user?

here is my current code:

Profiles controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

respond_to :html

def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
  respond_with(@profiles)
end

def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  respond_with(@profile)
end

def new
  @profile = Profile.new
  respond_with(@profile)
end

def edit
end

def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
  @profile.save
  respond_with(@profile)
end

def update
  @profile.update(profile_params)
  respond_with(@profile)
end

def destroy
  @profile.destroy
  respond_with(@profile)
end

private
  def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
 end

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :civil, :email, :level, :employment_date, :mobile, :folder, :title, :internal, :nationality, :vacation, :work_email, :experience)
end
end
```

Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates_associated :user
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use `devise`, it should be as simple as:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    @profile.user_id = current_user.id
    @profile.save
    respond_with(@profile)
  end
end
```

Devise creates that helper method for you. Check its [docs page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple, iv been struggling with this issue for days! thanks so much!